# Render JavaScript in a block

Tags: theming, nodes, javascript, blocks, hooks

The relevant items of the directory structure are the following:

- /template.php
- /js/custom.js

The following code is located in `template.php`. On page render, this function gets the value of a taxonomy term field with machine name `field_test` and passes it to a JavaScript function.

```
function bartikCustom_process_page(&$variables) {
  // Hook into color.module.
  if (module_exists('color')) {
     _color_page_alter($variables);
  }
  if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {
    $tid = $node->field_test['und'][0]['tid'];
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('test' => $term->name)), 'setting');
  }
```

In `custom.js`, the JavaScript function manipulates the variable to obtain further data.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        var testMe = Drupal.settings.mymodule.test;
        // Append the 'test' var to a Google Charts Service query string as a SELECT statement to call back a chart with controller
    }
});
```

How can I print out the resultant Google Chart into a block? Do I need to use the `#attach` function?

I'm still new to Drupal APIs so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this instead of rendering it to a js you can create a custom block. If you are using views create a block view with type content. Add [views conditional](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjr-o7Yr9vWAhWFNo8KHQHCAW4QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fviews_conditional&usg=AOvVaw1z3yR4TKUDt6Qp6ioUpy2l) module for filteration. Follow these steps.

1. Create a block from view with Show content.
2. Add field_test in the Fields.
3. Adds Views condition field.
4. From If this field dropdown select the field you want to check.
5. Enter the value in This value field i.e. (Term id for Cheese or Apple).
6. And then in Then Output this textarea add "Your favorite food is Cheese which is a Dairy".
7. And then in Otherwise, Output this textarea add "Your favorite food is Apple which is a Fruit".
8. Save the view and your place the created block in any region.

[image]

Comment: This is a really clean explanation, but unfortunately not what I am looking for. I left out some details in my initial post because I made the incorrect assumption it wouldn't make a difference. The javascript function is actually the google charts service. Editing now.